# Publishing React component to NPM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package, package.json

It is my first time publishing to NPM.I have a React menu component and I published it using this [method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-publish-a-reactjs-component-to-npm/). There is my folder structure and everything I want to publish are inside lib folder. After publishing I installed and tried it in another React project. I have imported and it is in node_modules folder as in screenshots, but it is giving `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-burger-navmenu' in 'C:\Users\yanke\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\burger-test\src'`

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react-burger-navmenu",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple menu component for React",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Saidamir-Sh/react-burger-navmenu.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "[\"menu\"",
    "\"react\"",
    "\"ui\"]"
  ],
  "author": "Saidamir",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Saidamir-Sh/react-burger-navmenu/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Saidamir-Sh/react-burger-navmenu#readme",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.4"
  }
}
```

**Menu.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import './styles/_index.scss'

interface Props {
    children?: JSX.Element|JSX.Element[]
    className?: string
    position?: string
}

const Menu = (props: Props) => {

    // show hide sidebar
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState<boolean>(false)

    // collapse side bar
    const ToggleMenu = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive)
    }

  return (
      <>
       <div onClick={ToggleMenu} className={isActive ? `hamburger hamburger-${props.position}  is-active` : `hamburger hamburger-${props.position}`} id="hamburger-3">
            <span className="line"></span>
            <span className="line"></span>
            <span className="line"></span>
            </div>
        <section id={!isActive ? 'menu' : 'menu-active'} className={`${props.className} ${props.position}`}>
            {props.children}
        </section>
      </>
    )
}

Menu.Header = (props: Props) => <header className={props.className}>{props.children}</header>;
Menu.Body = (props: Props) => <main className={props.className}>{props.children}</main>;
Menu.Footer = (props: Props) => <footer className={props.className}>{props.children}</footer>;

export default Menu
```

**index.tsx**

```
import Menu from "./components/Menu";

export default Menu
```

---

[image: Folder Structure]
[image: When imported it is showing right path.If you click on it, it will direct to package folder]

[image: And also it has correct files in node_modules]

Answer (score 0):

1. Ditch Cyrillic and spaces in the path (might not be the problem, but it's better without them);
2. In your `package.json` the entry point has to be different. According to the link what you provided: you need something like `"main":"Menu.js"`;
3. Add 'typescript', 'react-tsx' and some other more relevant tags to your question;
4. Your `dependencies` have to go into `peerDependencies`.
5. Try to manually copy the module files into your test directory. I am running a shell script for that (note: you might need to edit the script itself):

```
clear && cd && cd Documents/Repos/random-people && cp -r lib index.js package.json ~/Documents/Repos/test-directory/node_modules/randomized-people && cd && cd Documents/Repos/test-directory && node index.js
```

I'll explain what it does:
clears terminal, changes directory to home, changes directory to my local npm package files, copies them into `node_modules` of test-directory, changes directory to test-directory and runs the js file.

P.S: I might've missed some stuff, I am not really good with TS :)